# Can't install react-scripts E403

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I am kind of new to npm, nodejs, react ... Actually, I am currently just trying to run something that was given to me and I am strangely able to install everything but react-scripts.

Here's the commmand I have tried: `npm install react-scripts` or `npm install -g react-scripts`

Here's the error:

```
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fs.realpath
npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy.
npm ERR! 403 
npm ERR! 403 It was specified as a dependency of 'glob'
```

I have set ssl to False and set the registry this way:

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Here's my npm and node version:

- node v12.18.3
- npm v6.14.6

I have set my proxy using:

```
npm config set proxy http://username:password@proxy.company.com:port
npm config set https-proxy http://username:password@proxy.company.com:port
```

I had a "+" in my password that I have replaced by %2B but it was already well taken into account an actually I have managed to install every others packages

I have tested `npm cache clean -- forced` and  `rm -rf node__modules`

My OS is a REDHAT 7.5 with no admin right.

I have exhausted my possibilities and can't find anymore interesting things to test on internet.
Well if you have any idea, I would gladly give it a test.

Thank you in advance,
Rémi

Comment: use a VPN and try again

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It may be a solution but not for me. VPN connexion are blocked.